# Why cant I use some GLFW methods

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, eclipse-cdt, glfw

I'm using Linux OS and Eclipse. For some reason eclipse does not recognise some of the GLFW commands despite the fact that glfw3.h is included properly. I'm unable to use GLFWwindow, glfwCreateWindow and glfwDestoyWindow. Anyone know why?

## Edit

Just to be specific my IDE is underlining these methods as if they are not defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()){
        return 0;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(680, 480, "test", NULL, NULL);

    cin.get();

    if (window){
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to [initialize the library](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#ga317aac130a235ab08c6db0834907d85e). I suggest you read the [quick tutorial](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html) before continuing.

Comment: Do you *link* with the library? [There's an article that explain how to build with the library as well](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html). Always read the documentation and references before asking question.

Comment: Well you've jumped to the conclusion quickly. The point is that my IDE is underlining these methods as if they're not defined. I've updated the above code just for you ;).

Comment: I'm not trying to compile anything at the moment, because it would obviously fail I just don't understand why my IDE doesn't recognise these methods (unless I define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB above includes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the Eclipse editor in C/C++ mode uses the compiler to generate its symbol database, so unless you build the editor will not recognize new symbols.

So the solution is to actually build your project, even if the editor tells you there are errors.

Comment: Thanks It's working now. I didn't know that in eclipse you have to compile your program before it can recognise methods, that is just odd.

Comment: Eclipse shows false errors on a fairly regular basis. Sometimes building the project helps. Sometimes you need to clean the project to force a fresh build. Sometimes it gets so stuck in an error state that it refuses to even start a build, even though the project *would* build successfully.